# Is there any library for measuring data complexity of image datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I know that there are some libraries for measuring data complexity. For example:

https://github.com/lpfgarcia/ECoL

https://github.com/jcelias98/Complexity-Measures

But I'm not sure if they can be applied to images. Is there any library like these ones for dealing with images?